# Serving files from Apache and Tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, tomcat

I've trying to rebuild a server that needs to serve content from both Tomcat 6.0.16 and Apache HTTPD 2.2.3 on a RedHat 4.1.2 server.

I need a specific directory (it's called 'client') from the Apache DocumentRoot to be handled by Apache, and the rest by Tomcat. So I've got the Java app running at someserver.com:8080, and the client directory sitting in the DocumentRoot directory, and Apache running on port 80. The Java app is configured to run at /.

Here's what's in my httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/share/www/"

ProxyPass / http://someserver.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://someserver.com:8080/
```

This part of the proxy works, but I still get 404 on anything in http://someserver.com/client.

How should I go about getting this set up correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an exclusion with the `!` syntax, e.g.:

```
....
ProxyPass /client !
ProxyPass / http://someserver.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://someserver.com:8080/
```